# how to vertical center a form in React Native

Tags: reactjs, react-native, flexbox

I want to align vertical a form.

import React, { Component } from 'react';
    import { Container, Header, Content, Form, Item, Input, Button, Text } from 'native-base';
    import { StyleSheet } from 'react-native';

```
export default class FormExample extends Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <Container>
                <Content>
                    <Form style={styles.container}>
                        <Item>
                            <Input placeholder="Email" />
                        </Item>
                        <Item last>
                            <Input placeholder="Password" />
                        </Item>
                        <Button block>
                            <Text>Submit</Text>
                        </Button>
                    </Form>
                </Content>
            </Container>
        );
    }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    container: {
        flex: 1,
        margin: 25,
        alignItems: "center"
    }
```

});

my application looks like this.

[image: act]

Comment: since you are using some ui-element library it is better to refer to their documentation.In general though since all items are layed out in React Native in columns,I think with the container style set as {flex:1,justifyContent:'center'} should work.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> This is the line you need to add to content props

`contentContainerStyle={{flexGrow : 1, justifyContent : 'center'}}>`

```
<Container>
                <Content
contentContainerStyle={{flexGrow : 1, justifyContent : 'center'}}>
                    <Form style={styles.container}>
                        <Item>
                            <Input placeholder="Email" />
                        </Item>
                        <Item last>
                            <Input placeholder="Password" />
                        </Item>
                        <Button block>
                            <Text>Submit</Text>
                        </Button>
                    </Form>
                </Content>
            </Container>
        );
```